# Embed basic python game into web?

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-2.7

I wrote a basic python 2.7 game using things like `print`, `for`, `if`, `else`, etc.  I also made a website to hold the game downloads.  I was wondering if there is a way to embed the python game directly into the HTML5 website.  All of the other questions that I looked at contained links to non-existant websites.

Comment: Can you give us more information? How it is displayed, some example code, what you have already tried and such...

Comment: @Zizouz212 It's just a text adventure (I'm a begginer) and I haven't tried anything.  My code is very basic.  Is there a way that I could convert it to JavaScript or something?

Comment: So in essence, you're using the `print` statement to essentially display text?

Comment: Do you understand what `print`ing does behind the scenes?

Comment: @Zizouz212 No.  Can you explain?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print

Comment: I'm not familiar with javascript (I have some experience in java though), but here's what I see you would have to do: Redirect `print` to a separate file, not `sys.stdout`, send to an output stream, and have javascript display the information received in the stream in the browser.

Comment: @Zizouz212  
What would be the python (and if you know the JavaScript) for that? Would I have to change the print keyword and use something else or add code to redirect it?

Comment: @JakAttk123 It's not really possible to turn your "text adventure" game written in Python into something that can be played on the Web via a Web Browser without lot of rework and redesign. In essence you have to change the way the inputs/outputs work into request/responses with form(s0 and/or AJAX and JavaScript. It is **not** trivial.

Comment: Actually, porting text adventures to server-in-python+js is pretty simple, there are a number of libraries which automate the COMET/AJAX calls, and [jqconsole](https://github.com/replit/jq-console) handles displaying the output quite well.  I usually use divmod's [Athena](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Nevow/0.11.1) from the Nevow project.  Bit of boiler plate, and replace your `print()`s with `callRemote`s and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want and how the game does I/O, but I'd check out [pypy.js](http://pypyjs.org), it's a version of [pypy](http://pypy.org/) running in the browser, capable of basic I/O and what not, that would require a minimal amount of reworking your current setup.  For faster loading, you could use the same toolchain as pypy.js to compile your python code to C, and the C to asm.js.  That would require reworking your code to valid RPython, which requires runtime variables to be statically typed and a few other restrictions.  It would allow your game to run in the console at near native speed.

If you want the game code running on a web server, a COMET/AJAX solution is the way to go.  I usually use Athena LivePage from the [Nevow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Nevow/0.11.1) for that type of thing.  A 'drop-in' solution would be to use something like ShellInABox or PyInABox to run a server-side shell, and the run your python script inside the shell, running as a no-permissions user inside a chroot.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, I'm not familiar with *javascript* (I have some experience in *java* though), but here's what I see you would have to do: Redirect print to a separate file, not `sys.stdout`, send to an output stream, and have javascript display the information received in the stream in the browser.

About javascript, I'm not entirely sure.

But here is a little guidance for your python code:

```
print "Hi! I'm Zin"
```

to...

```
print >> (destination file), "Hi! I'm Zin"
print >> sys.stderr, "Hi I'm Zin" # Will print to Python's built in error stream.
```

Comment: Just found this: http://www.brython.info/  What do you think?

Comment: @JakAttk123 It looks pretty neat, but it's a Python 3 library. Not sure if there is one for Python 2. Aside from that, it looks like you should go up for it.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't be too hard to make the switch.  I'll try it.

Comment: Your biggest changes will be changing `print` to a function, rather than the statement, and `input()` rather than `raw_input()`

Comment: It seems cool but when I tried to add a test program, it just prompted the input and didn't document.write() anything.  Any idea if I could change the python code to make it understand it better?

Comment: That's strange... It should work with anything that has a `write()` method. How did you try writing it? There's a typo above...

Comment: I just used print.... I also wanted to make it like an embedded console (or something like that) instead of prompting the input with a prompt window.